# Has players coming to plead their case ever get a call rescinded?

Tags: football, officiating

Haven't watched a lot of soccer, but when a player gets given a card, you always see their team just start to huddle around the ref and it seems like try to plead their case?

But in the amount of matches I've seen, I don't think I've seen it often that a call gets rescinded.

Does it happen every once in a while or does that 'case pleading' has another use (or is something else entirely?)

Comment: It's much less important nowadays because of VAR and it's a lot done/undone. I saw a play (2023/09/20) in UEFA Champions League where the italian player was sent off and there instantly was kind of a brawl around the ref, all complaining. Watching the replay, the referee reversed the call: red card canceled, yellow card to the other player. So I'd say that now, it's just a cultural thing to keep putting pressure on the ref. In the old days, efficiency was close to zero.

Comment: In competitions without VAR it's a rare case. I've seen it actually happen in 3rd division in Germany last week. The referee reversed a penalty call after talking to the assistant.

Comment: I recall reading about an incident years ago in which a referee gave a blatant free kick in the wrong direction, and in the ensuing argument, he realised he was colour-blind and had gotten the two teams mixed up. It didn't say whether he reversed his decision or not, and I so far haven't been able to find any reference to the incident.

Comment: Putting a psychological pressure on a referee can affect his future decisions. They may hesitate to book another player from the same team for a small offence. Or book one of the opposing players without hesitation when opportunity arrives. This can easily backfire though.